# Compile docker-grafana-graphite on Windows

Tags: docker, makefile, build, grafana, graphite

Trying to complete this tutorial to run grafana on Windows, at this point of compilation I kept got this error:

```
PS C:\Programs\Others\LocustReport\docker-grafana-graphite> make up
mkdir -p \
                data/whisper \
                data/elasticsearch \
                data/grafana \
                log/graphite \
                log/graphite/webapp \
                log/elasticsearch
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
make: *** [prep] Error 1
PS C:\Programs\Others\LocustReport\docker-grafana-graphite>
```

Please any workaorund to get it compiled?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run a linux vm (I use virtualbox) to build the image on.